# About CoinLink.cc

Tags: mining

Can anyone explain what the CoinLink.cc project is about, please?

Link: https://coinlink.cc/en/#features

I've read the info in that link, but I don't get it.

From this site: https://themerkle.com/coinlink-lets-users-hide-urls-and-earn-monero-in-the-process/

"Coinlink is an interesting venture..., as it allows users to "hide" existing website URLs and earn some money by doing so."

But, what does this mean? "hide" what from whom and where? What is it that I'm meant to "hide" and why?

Is this some kind of away to scam the visitors to my website by "hiding" the fact that I'm using my visitors' computer to mine Monero for me?

I'm a little confused, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a good photo, I want to earn money at the same time sending it to others, then I "hide" the url of the photo and publish [it](https://coinlink.cc/en/link/go/287) to all. You see the photo after mining, I get monero.

It's more like buying a ticket.

Comment: I think I'm beginning to get my head around it, thanks. One thing that's still a little unclear to me: I want to see your photo and I click on your 'it' link. Will I then be informed about the fact that I'll have to do a little mining and for how long, before I get to see the photo?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: The difficulty level was setted when created the link, the page you saw after you click on "it" showed you the hash rete and percentage. I don't konw whether we can guess the time from the percentage.